# How do I open a file in VS Code terminal by partially matching the file name?

Tags: bash, terminal, visual-studio-code

If I have a file named `w5_align_example.cpp`, how do I open that file in VS Code integrated terminal by only supplying the word `align`?

`code w5_align_sample.cpp` would open it but I sometimes only remember the keyword `align` unless I search in a separate command to see what the file begins with. I want to open in a single command instead.

I've tried:

- `$ ls | grep "align" | code` which gives me `Run with 'code -' to read output from another program (e.g. 'echo Hello World | code -').` error.
- `$ ls | grep "align" | code -` opens up a new file called `code-stdin-sfd.txt` with the text `w5_align_example.cpp` inside.

What would be the simplest (i.e. shortest) command to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ls | grep "align" | xargs -I{} code {}
```

or

```
code $(ls | grep "align")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `*`. It matches any string and can be used multiple times.

```
code *align*
```

In some shells, you can combine this with tab completion. Just type:

```
code *align*
```

And then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. This will fill in the rest of the file name, but it will beep if there is more than one option.